# timer not shown on my swf

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler);
    function countdownHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{   
        countdown1.text = 100-myTimer.currentCount+"seconds Left";
        if(myTimer.currentCount==100){gotoAndStop(66)}  
    }
function start_btn_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(getLevelFrame(1));
    myTimer.start();
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

I'm trying to put a countdown timer on my stage but the timer was not shown on the stage. The word that printed is not "seconds Left" but it was "secons eft". I can run on other scene but not this.

Comment: Your problem may be caused by a font embedding issue. Can you add the code where you define and add countdown1 to the stage? Or, if you have it placed on the stage on your timeline, check the font embedding properties for it

Answer (score 2):

As Kaushal De Silva suggested it is definitely a font embedding problem.

Here's how to embed a font:

1. Select a TextField on your stage
2. Click on the `Embed` button in the properties panel

   [image: Embed fonts in flash]
3. Choose the character ranges you need

   [image]
4. Click `OK`

That's pretty much it.